# How do I get my C# custom class array to correctly track member elements?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to achieve the following - When a user enters a barcode in ProductsListCBX, the app should look up the product and load the product info. My custom class has a field `ItemCount`, and I have an array `TransactionRecord[50]` that stores each transaction's info (`ItemCount, ItemName, ItemUnitCost`) as a record of the array. My issue is the `ItemCount` field seems to be retaining the `ItemCount` from the last transaction when it should initialize each new record of the array with an `ItemCount = 0`. The item count just increases sequentially as I loop through the array (displaying them gives 1, 2, 3, ...  when it should have a default of 1, 1, 1, ... ). When adding a new transaction, if the barcode matches a barcode that's already in one of the transactions, then the app should just increase the `ItemCount` for that transaction.  Am I doing something wrong with my code? Please assist, I've provided the code below.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Printing;

namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class POSHubForm : Form
    {
        public POSHubForm(string username, string org)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UsernameLBL.Text = username;
            CompanyLBL.Text = org;
        }

        Transaction[] TransactionRecord = new Transaction[50];
        readonly Product SaleItem = new Product();
        string saleString = String.Empty;
        string MasterSaleString = String.Empty;
        string footerString = String.Empty;
        double MasterCost = 0;
        double totalCost = 0;
        int salesCount = 0;
        int RecordCount = 0;
        int AllTempTotal = 0;
        int TempTotal = 0;
        int TotalSalesToday = 0;
        
        private void CreateTransactionRecord()
        {         
            if (ProductListCBX.Text != String.Empty)
            {
                try
                {
                    string itemDataLocation = "D:\\MyApp\\Barcodes\\" + ProductListCBX.Text + ".txt";
                    TransactionRecord[RecordCount] = new Transaction();
                    SaleItem.LoadProduct(itemDataLocation);

                    saleString += SaleItem.GetPaddedName() + "E" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", SaleItem.GetPrice()) + "\n";
                    MasterSaleString += SaleItem.GetPaddedName() + "E" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", SaleItem.GetPrice()) + "\n";
                    ProductInfoLBL.Text = SaleItem.GetName();
                    totalCost += SaleItem.GetPrice();
                    MasterCost += SaleItem.GetPrice();
                    TotalCostLBL.Text = "E" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", totalCost);
                    ItemCostLBL.Text = "E" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", SaleItem.GetPrice());
                    salesCount++;
                    CountBtn.Text = Convert.ToString(salesCount);

                    for (int k = 0; k <= RecordCount ; k++)
                    {
                        if(Convert.ToInt64(ProductListCBX.Text) == TransactionRecord[k].GetBarCode())
                        {
                            TransactionRecord[k].IncreaseItemCount();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            TransactionRecord[RecordCount].IncreaseItemCount();
                            TransactionRecord[RecordCount].SetBarCode(Convert.ToInt64(ProductListCBX.Text));
                            TransactionRecord[RecordCount].SetUnitPrice(Convert.ToDouble(SaleItem.GetPrice()));
                            TransactionRecord[RecordCount].SetItemName(SaleItem.GetName());
                            TransactionRecord[RecordCount].SetTotalPrice();
                        }
                    }

                    string Record = String.Empty;
                    string Items = String.Empty;

                    for (int n = 0; n <= RecordCount; n++)
                    {
                        Record += TransactionRecord[n].CreateSaleRecord();
                        Items += Convert.ToString(TransactionRecord[n].GetItemCount()) + ", ";
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show(Record + "\n\n" + Items);
                    RecordCount++;

                    ItemDescriptionTBX.Text += "  > " + SaleItem.GetName().PadRight(30) + "E" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", SaleItem.GetPrice()) + "\r\n";
                }

                catch (FileNotFoundException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("The product you entered does not exist");
                }

                catch (Exception x)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
                }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Item list cannot be empty. Type, browse, or scroll the item list to add products for a sale.");
            }

            ProductListCBX.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}


//EDIT - This is the Transaction class


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyApp
{
    class Transaction
    {
        private long ItemBarCode;
        private double ItemUnitPrice = 0;
        private double ItemTotalPrice = 0;
        private string ItemName = String.Empty;
        private int ItemCount = 0;

        public long GetBarCode()
        {
            return ItemBarCode;
        }

        public string GetItemName()
        {
            return ItemName;
        }

        public int GetItemCount()
        {
            return ItemCount;
        }

        public double GetUnitPrice()
        {
            return Convert.ToDouble(ItemCount * ItemUnitPrice);
        }

        public double GetTotalPrice()
        {
            return Convert.ToDouble(ItemCount * ItemUnitPrice);
        }

        public string CreateSaleRecord()
        {
            return Convert.ToString(ItemCount).PadRight(3) + " x " + ItemName.PadRight(50) + "- E" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", GetTotalPrice()) + "\n";
        }

        public void ReverseItem()
        {

        }

        public void IncreaseItemCount()
        {
            ItemCount++;
        }

        public void DecreaseItemCount()
        {
            ItemCount--;
        }

        public void SetBarCode(long Code)
        {
            ItemBarCode = Code;
        }

        public void SetItemName(string Name)
        {
            ItemName = Name;
        }

        public void SetUnitPrice(double Price)
        {
            ItemUnitPrice = Price;
        }

        public void SetTotalPrice()
        {
            ItemTotalPrice = Convert.ToDouble(ItemCount * ItemUnitPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We will need to see specifics of the `Transaction` class I think. Likely there is something wrong with your getter logic, or the constructor on the class itself. The included code snippet does not really give any info on what is amiss here, as we don't see the definitions of GetItemCount() nor IncreaseItemCount()

Comment: Quick but unrelated style tip, prefer .NET properties over the Java style getter methods, its a lot cleaner to read and simpler to write, and the compiler generates the getter method on its own anyway. I'll adjust the class with idiomatic styling in mind once posted

Comment: Your loop through the array should record whether it found a match and only change the last element in the array *once* after the loop is over, not *each time though the loop*. That being said, a nice `Dictionary<Int64, Transaction>` rather than an array would be much preferred and avoid having to write search loops at all.

Comment: @Narish I just updated the question to add the class. I've been trying to inspect my procedures and I'm drawing a blank. Ideally, `TransactionRecord[i].ItemCount = 0` at initialization, then `IncreaseItemCount()` simply increments by one when a new record is added.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever admittedly, I'm not too familiar with that method, although I think I understand the implementation well enough. In the end, I need to print a list of each record alongside its count, e.g `1   x PRODUCT NAME                       - $20.00`. If there is more than one occurrence of the product, does `Dictionary <Int64, Transaction>` still work? Am I able to get the number of `Transactions` linked to each `Int64` key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some adjustments to your class. Since there isn't much validation logic we can definitely collapse your get and set methods into auto properties. This makes the class much more compact and easier to use.

```cs
public class Transaction
{
    public long ItemBarCode { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set;} = string.Empty;
    public uint ItemCount { get; set; } = 1;

    //these both can be decimal type, or double, your call
    public double ItemUnitPrice { get; set; }
    public double ItemTotalPrice => ItemCount * ItemUnitPrice; //this is a readonly property, imagine this as a getter method. This is a computed value, there is no real need for a setter method

    //the following method could be made a bit cleaner by formatting interpolated strings, read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated
    public string CreateSaleRecord() => Convert.ToString(ItemCount).PadRight(3) + " x " + ItemName.PadRight(50) + "- E" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", GetTotalPrice()) + "\n";

    public void ReverseItem()
    {
        //nothing provided, left as is
    }
}
```

So lets summarize the key change `public uint ItemCount { get; set; } = 1;`

1. You can access this with `transaction.ItemCount`
2. You can now increment with `transaction.ItemCount++` and `transaction.ItemCount--`. This being an unsigned int `uint` it should never be decremented into negative values so be sure to have service logic to block that from happening
3. Notice the `= 1` at the end. This ensures that on construction of a new object, this property will initialize to 1. I am not sure why you originally initialize the value to 0 if you would prefer it to start at 1

Now that being said, this really should be using something like a `Dictionary<long, Transaction>` to properly lookup the exact record. You are currently using a global `RecordCount` variable to track the current place in the array but this is very needless complexity

I am a bit confused by the logic, but it seems as if you are searching the records to see if that product exists, and if so, increment the count. If not, then simply "add" a new transaction (by essentially clobbering whatever is at the RecordCount index). Simplify all of this: first attempt to read and update the record, and if not, add the record to the Dictionary.

```cs
Dictionary<long, Transaction> records = new(); //key = bar code
//add records here

if (long.TryParse(ProductListCBX.Text, out long textCode))
{
    if (records.ContainsKey(textCode)) 
    {
        records[textCode].ItemCount++;
    }
    else 
    {
        records.Add(new Transaction()
        {
            //item count is already init to 1
            ItemBarCode = textCode,
            ItemUnitPrice = SaleItem.Price,
            ItemName = SaleItem.Name,
            //total price is available on-demand, no need to set
        });
    }
}
else
{
    //Handle scenario if you could not parse
}
```

Very important to note that Dictionaries boast constant time complexity on lookups, vs executing a search operation *every* single time you need to make updates to the records collection. There will never be a need for a global variable that is manually tracking the current record being searched in the array also. That just sounds like future debugging hell and violates proper separation of responsibilities (the class containing `RecordCount` should not be tracking the current order being processed, at least not in the way done here). If that barcode is guaranteed to be unique then its a perfect candidate as a dictionary key

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do, and I've just been trying to get it to work in any way before I can think of optimizing it. Thanks though, I'll try the `Dictionary<long, BarCode>` implementation and see how that pans out. It even sounds simpler and if it does away with the need for the global index `RecordCount`, even better.

Comment: Dictionary works beautifully! Tweaked the code a bit, but I have the exact behaviour I needed. Thanks a million.

Comment: Glad to have helped! Yes, if you ever need to store objects into a place that you will be constantly reading from, `Dictionary<T, U>` and related classes are your go-to. In most other scenarios, a `List<T>` is sufficient, or `IEnumerable<T>` for fluent compositions that are lazily evaluated. Keep arrays for when you explicitly need something that barebones but fast/small. .NET has a lot of great collection types, including their thread-safe variants, I highly recommend spending some time in the docs to learn about the options available. We are given a lot of great tools out of the box

Comment: Start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/commonly-used-collection-types) to learn more about the different offerings. Also, prefer to use the generic versions of these, as they will offer much better type safety

Comment: I'll definitely give it a good read, so far you've given me nothing but great advice.